# Save 2 NSArray data to 2 files in NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to save data from 2 arrays to document dir, The first one was saved, but the second one not!!

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];


    NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];

    NSString *rangePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Range.plist"];
    NSString *indexPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Select.plist"];

    [finalMutable writeToFile:rangePath atomically:YES];
    [finalIndex writeToFile:indexPath atomically:YES];

}
```

updated:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [finalIndex addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]];
}
```

Comment: Pls add  what does  finalMutable and  finalIndex contains,  finalIndex must be problem

Comment: They both have same, this's NSLog: finalMutable count: 5, finalIndex count: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to save 2nd file, because finalIndex Array contains NSIndexPath objects.NSIndexPath objects can't be stored in plist files.
Data types supported in plist are:
Array,
Dictionary,
String,
Number,
Data, 
Date,
Boolean